# Connect to remote mysql hosting (godaddy)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, remote-access

I can connect to my `MySQL XAMPP` in my local machine. Now, I want to connect to my webhosting inside a GoDaddy account (It's the cheapest type of account though) I am using Visual Studio 2015.

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

Dim conn As MySqlConnection

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "SERVER = 166.xxx.xxx.xxx; PORT = 3306; DATABASE = myDB; UID = myUSER; PASSWORD = myPASSWORD"

    Try
      conn.Open()
      MessageBox.Show("Connected!")
      conn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Failed")
    Finally
      conn.Dispose()
    End Try

 End Sub
End Class
```

This is the error I am getting while connecting:

> Authentication to host '166.xxx.xxx.xxx' for user 'myUSER' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'myUSER'@''49.150.102.%' to database 'myDB'

I am getting a wildcard `%` because I placed my IP to the access host using 49.150.102.%. I also tried to place my whole octet of IP and gets the same result.

For the purpose of this question, I changed the exact value of my connection info for security reasons.

Comment: Does `myUSER` have access to the remote database?

Comment: good question sir. let me see it, and figure out how. thanks

Comment: If the credentials are all correct, it does seem like `myUSER` doesn't have access to the database, as @Tim says

Comment: yap, @Tim the user is not authorized. I made some changes now. It is now working fine. Thanks. PS: I didnt change any from the code. I changed the authorization of the user inside godaddy. Thanks guys.